# How do I prove if $x$ is an even prime and $x \geq 10$ then $x$ is divisible by 3?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing

I know that for a number to be divisible by 3 the sum of its digits must be divisible by 3.

It is also known that all primes greater than 2 and 3 are of the form $6k \pm 1$, but I need even primes and this is where I'm stuck.

Comment: There is only *one* even prime! Further, the only prime divisible by $3$ is… $3$.

Comment: You should not try to rely only on the title to formulate the problem to be solved.   Instead use the body of the Question to give a self-contained problem statement  (setup and goal).  This will give you a better chance of getting the statement across clearly to Readers.

Answer (score 4):

The set of even primes that are at least $10$ equals the empty set. Every element of the empty set is divisible by $3$.